# Making 'git log' ignore commits with 0 changes

Tags: git, gitlab

I have to make a csv to compute our change volume based on `git log` and there is a commit in the repo that has 0 files changed/0 insertions & deletions and it completely throws off the format of the csv despite using pretty format.

The command I run is the following

`git log --since=2020-01-01 --until=2021-02-01 --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%aD","%s",' --shortstat --no-merges | paste - - - > file.csv`

How do I make it so that the command ignores any commits that do not have any insertions or deletions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process the output to drop such lines.

for example : `grep` for lines containing `files? changed`, and use `-B1` to keep the preceeding line

```
... | grep -B1 -E "files? changed" | ...
```

`awk` or `sed` would also fit the bill, or you can use your favorite scripting language (`python`, `ruby`, `perl` ...)

Comment: Yup. To lose the interstitials I'd do `git log --pretty=etc --shortstat | sed 'N;/\n /p;D'`.

Comment: ... and to do the pasting make it `… | sed 'N;s/\n / /p;D'`

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this question but thank you so much. The `sed` commands cleaned it up the best for me